# Is "to" required in "While listening to the salesman…"?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

> While listening to the salesman, the narrator starts thinking about his own business

Is the sentence grammatically correct? I am not sure whether it would be "listening to" or "listening". Is there any other way to form the sentence?

Comment: You _listen to_ a sound or a person speaking.

Comment: "Listen" is an *intransitive* verb, so it cannot take a direct object. This means you need the preposition "to".

Answer (score 1):

As the comment by gotube mentions, the verb "*listen*" is intransitive, and so does not take a direct object. Thus you cannot "Listen {noun phrase}"  You can only "listen **to** {noun phrase}" or "listen **for** {noun phrase}". Thus

> While listening to the salesman, the narrator starts thinking about his own business.

is grammatically correct, and the "*to*": is required.

One can also "listen at", for example:

> John listened at the window, to hear what was being said inside.